# php дистанционно из html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Возможно ли, не залезая в php файл, в котором выбирается имя таблицы SQL, менять это имя на html странице ?

Т.е. в php файле- SELECT FROM table1.
Надо table1 поменять на table2 дистанционно с html страницы.

Comment: Передать имя таблицы через GET/POST запрос не?

Comment: "не залезая"  - нельзя. Телепатию для серверов еще не придумали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно можно, изучите передачу данных через тело запроса (POST/PUT) или через параметры запроса (GET), как работать с этими данными можно найти в [официальной документации PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php). По сути, вы создаете форму, в ней отправляете поле и получаете его на серверной стороне в соответствии с методом через который была произведена отправка.

По соображениям безопасности, не рекомендуется передавать в запрос название таблицы и разрешать его вводить пользователю. Если передача подобных данных идет с front-end, то скорее всего Вы делаете что-то неправильно, клиентская сторона не должна знать ничего о внутреннем устройстве и сущностях хранилища.